Uncaught SyntaxError in Laravel Pusher
I am learning Live messaging system development using Pusher and Laravel.  I am following this tutorial. https://webjourney.dev/laravel-pusher-real-time-chat-application-build-with-javascript-jquery
My blade file code is like below.
@extends('saas.frontend.layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="property-details-area">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p class="property-home-part">                        
                        {{ $information->name }}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="app">
            <div class="row">
        
                <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3 my-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter a user ..........">
                </div>
        
                <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">
                    <div class="box box-primary direct-chat direct-chat-primary">
        
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="direct-chat-messages" id="messages"></div>
                        </div>
        
                        <div class="box-footer">
                            <form action="#" method="post" id="message_form">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Type Message ..." class="form-control">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button type="submit" id="send_message"  class="btn btn-primary btn-flat">Send</button>
                                  </span>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
        
                    </div>
                </div>
        
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @push('style')
    <style>
        body{
            margin-top:20px;
            background:#eee;
        }
        .box {
            position: relative;
            border-radius: 3px;
            background: #ffffff;
            border-top: 3px solid #d2d6de;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            width: 100%;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }
        .box.box-primary {
            border-top-color: #3c8dbc;
        }

        .box-body {
            border-top-left-radius: 0;
            border-top-right-radius: 0;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .direct-chat .box-body {
            border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
            position: relative;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .direct-chat-messages {
            padding: 10px;
            height: 150px;
            overflow: auto;
        }
    </style>
@endpush
    @push('script')
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src ="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
            import Pusher from 'pusher-js';

            window.Pusher = Pusher;

            window.Echo = new Echo({
                broadcaster: 'pusher',
                key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
                cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
                forceTLS: true
            });

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(document).on('click','#send_message',function (e){
                    e.preventDefault();

                    let username = $('#username').val();
                    let message = $('#message').val();

                    if(username == '' || message == ''){
                        alert('Please enter both username and message')
                        return false;
                    }

                    $.ajax({
                        method:'post',
                        url:'/send-message',
                        data:{username:username, message:message},
                        success:function(res){
                            //
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

            window.Echo.channel('chat')
            .listen('.message',(e)=>{
                $('#messages').append('<p><strong>'+e.username+'</strong>'+ ': ' + e.message+'</p>');
                $('#message').val('');
            });
        </script>
    @endpush
@endsection

But I am getting error Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module at console.

How can I solve this error ?

Does this answer your question? ES2015 import doesn't work (even at top-level) in Firefox

I'd be glad to help you resolve the "Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at the top level of a module" error you're encountering in your Laravel Pusher chat application's Blade file.
Understanding the Error:
This error arises because modern JavaScript modules (using the  attribute) have a strict requirement: import statements must be placed at the very beginning of the script, before any other code. This ensures proper module loading and execution.
Solution:
To fix this error, you have two primary approaches:
1. Move import Statements to the Top:
Within the <script> tag in your @push('script') section, rearrange the code so that the import statements for Echo and Pusher come before any other JavaScript code:


@push('script')
    <script>
        import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
        import Pusher from 'pusher-js';

        window.Pusher = Pusher;

        // Rest of your JavaScript code
    </script>
@endpush



2. Use a Bundler (Recommended):
If your project is more complex or you plan to use multiple modules, consider using a JavaScript bundler like Webpack or Parcel. These tools can handle module dependencies, including imports, and bundle your code into a single, optimized file.
Here's a general breakdown of the bundler approach:

Install a bundler: Choose your preferred bundler (e.g., npm install webpack or npm install parcel).
Configure the bundler: Create a configuration file that specifies entry points (main JavaScript
files) and output locations for bundled files.
Update your Blade file: Instead of individual <script> tags, reference the bundled file generated by the bundler.

